Current equation for a circuit containing 5 basic elements in series
Does a general equation (for current) exist for a circuit containing the five elements namely e(dc), e(ac), R, L (active/inactive), C (charged/uncharged) in series? If yes, can i derive from it the equations for the sub circuits that can be made by connecting some of the elements in series by simply removing the other elements? I believe the number of such sub-circuits should be $\Sigma5Ci = 31$.

A general solution does exist, you just need to solve the corresponding second-order differential equation, with initial conditions consistent with the initial inductor current $i^0_L$ and initial capacitor charge $v^0_C$. No, in general you can't remove elements and solve the sub-circuits first, and then combine the solutions.
What you can do is superpose the four solutions with:

Only a DC source, $i^0_L = 0$, $v^0_C = 0$
Only an AC source, $i^0_L = 0$, $v^0_C = 0$
Non-zero $i^0_L$, no source, $v^0_C = 0$
Non-zero $v^0_C$, no source, $i^0_L = 0$

